# What shade of meaning is the word "proper" supposed to add to the sentence?

Tags: meaning, syntax

From Bram Stoker's "Dracula":

> At the very beginning of the seventeenth century it underwent a siege of three weeks and lost 13,000 people, the casualties of war **proper** being assisted by famine and disease.

From what I understand, the word "proper" modifies "war", in which case I presume I am right to believe that the closest definition of it is "strictly limited to a specified thing, place, or idea" (6th meaning presented in Merriam-Webster's dictionary), which somehow, at least to my impression, makes no difference?
How would the meaning change if "proper" were to be removed from the sentence?
Or does the word proper modify the part that comes after it?

This is the first time I have come across such a usage of the word, and perhaps I'm missing something, so I'd very much appreciate any help or input : )

Comment: In this case it means people who died as a **direct** result of war/combat (i.e. they were shot/stabbed/blown up/etc), and not people who died from **secondary** causes such as famine and disease.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some other dictionaries give a longer explanation. For example:

- "[You can add **proper** after a word to indicate that you are referring to the central and most important part of a place, event, or object and want to distinguish it from other things that are not regarded as being important or central to it.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/proper)" — Collins Dictionary
- "[belonging to the main, most important, or typical part](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proper)" — Cambridge Dictionary

---

The "casualties of war proper" would be those killed or injured by warfare itself. War kills or injures people directly, but it also brings about side effects like famine and disease, and the people harmed by those are then indirect victims of war (not harmed by bullets or bombs).

To me personally, this phrasing as used by Stoker here does have a bit of an old-fashioned sound to it. You could use "casualties of war itself" rather than "casualties of war proper" here.

---

Another such use of "proper" can involve territory. For example, the term "Ukraine proper" has been used occasionally to refer to the parts of Ukraine's 1991 territory not under Russian control, for example:

- "[Russia builds border fence between Crimea and Ukraine proper](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/12/28/russia-builds-border-fence-between-crimea-and-ukraine-proper)" (Al Jazeera, in 2018)
- "[It's unclear how many of Mariupol's residents fled to Russia and Russian-controlled territories, as opposed to going west, to Ukraine proper, or leaving for Western countries.](https://www.rferl.org/a/ukraine-russia-mariupol-doubts-reconstruction/32375926.html)" (RadioFreeEurope RadioLiberty, in 2023)

More territorial usages with Wikipedia articles include:

- "[China proper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_proper)", controversially used to denote only certain core Han areas
- "[Sweden proper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweden_proper)", used in earlier centuries when Sweden controlled Finland and other territories
- "[Norway Proper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norway_Proper)", excluding territories like Svalbard
- "[city proper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_proper)", used to refer to only the area within city limits, excluding suburbs and other parts of the metropolitan area that are towns or cities in their own right

Comment: Oh! This "itself" analogy is really what made it click for me, now I see! Much appreciated ❤️

Comment: To me the most relevant shade here is not direct/indirect, but the idea that the war is really underway, that it isn't rumours or things that seem warlike but an actual war: war as it really is, whatever it is that may properly be called "war".

Comment: "war proper" appears frequently in books about the nature of war, the ethics of war, strategies of warfare, the theory of conflict, etc. It's a philosophical/academic distinction to separate famine, disease, displacement, etc from "war".

Comment: @LukeSawczak Yes, the terminology *"war proper"* is commonly used in that way.  However, in the context of OP's quotation, it is clear that we are talking about *"casualties-of-war proper"* rather than *"casualties of war-proper"* - were it the latter the additional casualties would derive from unrest, violence, skirmishes, etc. in the build-up predating the full-on declared war.

Answer (score -2):

Modern English people will often use it as a prefix instead. For example: "Later on we should go the pub and get proper wasted"

Maybe the "proper" in the question is a prefix to what comes after? "the casualties of war are properly being assisted with death by famine and disease"

Comment: Proper as in "proper wasted" means to enhance the degree by which one gets wasted, which is an entirely different usage.

Comment: This should be "properly". Although I think this misuse of the adjective is not uncommon in casual British conversation. I don't think I've ever heard this slang use of "proper" in AmE.

Comment: @Barmar No, it shouldn’t be _properly_. When you go on a bender, you’re much more likely to say you get _proper wasted_ than _properly wasted_ (which, to me anyway, would imply getting wasted in an appropriate way). Similarly, something can be ‘proper nice’, but I don’t think I’ve ever heard ‘properly nice’. It is a very British thing, but adverbial _proper_ is quite commonplace and not slangy, just colloquial. (But as Phil says, it is a completely different use to the one in the Stoker quote and not actually relevant to the question here at all.)